# Firebase offline capabilities causing memory problems

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, offline-caching

I am developing a chat app that uses firebase database to store data. The usual approach while developing a chat app is to keep the database nodes synced so that you access the messages offline. So the problem rises when I implement the firebase offline capabilities to keep the data nodes synced. Firebase suggests two required steps for accessing data offline:

**Enabling disk persistance**

this is enabled according to the documentation by using this line of code (in my case I add it in application class):

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistanceEnabled(true);
```

and

**Keeping a node synced**

this is enabled by simply adding keepsynced(true) to any databasereference that you wish to keep synced, like this:

```
ChatNode.keepSynced(true);
```

**What is the difference between the two?**

According to the firebase team answers on this site, I deduced that:

**1)** (Disk persistance) stores the data on the device disk to use them when needed, and data is stored wether you write data or read data.

**a)** If you write data offline: data is stored on disk and is sent to database when you go online again.

**b)** If you read data offline: the listener that was read online and was kept in disk and stored, you will be able to read it offline from disk.

**2)** (keep synced true) will keep a database reference synced in 2 ways:

**a)** If you are also using (disk persistence) with (keep synced) you will be able to keep data synced on disk ... which seems to be the default behavior of (disk persistence).

**b)** If you are using (keep synced) alone then you only store to what is known as the app memory.

**The problem**

I did set both of the methods, but my app is now very laggy and slow and sometimes stops on its own.

**The question**

If all the things that I said above are true, then would this method of offline capability be a heavy load on my app?

If I kept many listeners synced and set persistence enabled, then would the disk become full of data? Should I clean the data? Is the data on disk cleaned by itself in both methods? Is data cleaned by itself from memory?

I want to avoid the lagging and slow response in my app, thanks for your help.

Comment: I am also getting the lagging and slow response on my iOS app. are you only experiencing this in android and not iOS? Does the laggy behavior happen only on real devices or on the simulator as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about your assumptions. If you are using `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);` means that Firebase will create a local copy of your database which also means that every change that is made while you are offline, will be added to a `queue`. So, as this queue grows, local operations and application startup will slow down. So the speed depends on the dimension of that queue. But rememeber, Firebase is designed as an online database that can work for short to intermediate periods of being disconnected and not as an offline database.

Second, if are using many listeners, don't forget to remove the listener accordingly to the life-cycle of your activity like this:

```
databaseReference.removeEventListener(valueEventListener);
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but I want to know who is responsible for cleaning the stored data on disk and memory me or firebase. If the stored data is causing the lag then the good approach would be to clean them, so how do I go about doing that?

Comment: You are. When you are getting back online, all the operations that were in the `queue` will be commited on Firebase server. This means that your `queue` will be empty at that moment.

Comment: So the queue on disk is released, then what is causing the lag?

Comment: I may be from other reasons. Let's say when apps will lose their socket connections when there is no visible activity. Android will pause background applications so they don't consume data and battery when the user isn't actively using it. When an activity becomes started again, the Firebase SDK should attempt to restore the websocket it uses to communicate with the server. This websocket is fully managed by the SDK. So this might be another reason.

Comment: Other chat apps (the popular ones) they manage everything online and offline no percent of lag or slowing down .....how do they manage this? Do you think I can achieve this functionality with firebase? What is your advice for preventing a laggy chat app in this case? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Yes, you can achieve this with Firebase. There are many chat apps examples over the internet that use Firebase database. But as response to your question, I suggest you try to reduce the amount of data that can be transfered and the number of connections as much as possible. Keep synced only the important nodes from your database. Hope i was helpful.

Comment: So stopping listeners on activity pause will do anything concerning lag? If yes then if I did keep synced a database reference and then I removed the listener of the database on activity close.Then the reference that I kept synced will be removed from memory and not disk. In this case who will remove this cached data? Thanks you have been helpful.

Comment: Will save resources and will save bandwith because will not listen anymore. You need to remove the listener accordingly to the life-cycle. If you have added the listener in `onStart` you have to remove it in `onStop`. If you have added the listener in `onResume` you have to remove it in `onPause`. If you have added the listener in `onCreate` you have to remove it in `onDestroy`. But remember `onDestroy` is not always called. There are 2 different concepts, listeners, which are always looking for changes in the database and the queue which can be full of operations while you are offline.

Comment: So I don't have to worry about single value event listener only about value event listeners and child added listeners?

Comment: Yes that's correct. If you are using `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` there is no need to remove the listener because as it says, it listen for changes only once.