# Can't retrieve data from Firebase using ValueEventListener

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: This is my database tree]

I'm trying to retrieve data from database and show it in an activity. The data is retrieved from database with a parent which corresponds to the previously clicked RecyclerView's position. When the data is retrieved using ValueEventListener, it shows that the variables are null.

I'm using intent to send the RecyclerView's position to other activity so it is able to retrieve the data from the clicked RecyclerView's child.

```
public void changeData(){
    final Intent intent = getIntent();
    Log.v("Locationsdsa", intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_LOCATION"));
    Log.v("LocationsdsaLOLOL", intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_POSITION"));
    DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Data");
    db.child(intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_LOCATION")).child(intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_POSITION")).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            placeName = dataSnapshot.child("nameResto").getValue(String.class);
            String restoAddress = dataSnapshot.child("restoAddress").getValue(String.class);
            String restoReview = dataSnapshot.child("restoReviews").getValue(String.class);
            String imgUrl = dataSnapshot.child("restoThumbnail").getValue(String.class);
            langitude = dataSnapshot.child("restoLangitude").getValue(Double.class);
            longitude = dataSnapshot.child("restoLongitude").getValue(Double.class);

            Log.v("langitude", String.valueOf(langitude));
            Log.v("longitude", String.valueOf(longitude));
            Log.v("name", placeName);
            Log.v("restoaddress", restoAddress);
            Log.v("reviewresto", restoReview);
            tvPlace.setText(placeName);
            tvAddress.setText(restoAddress);
            tvRating.setText(restoReview);
            Picasso.get().load(imgUrl).resize(200, 200).centerInside().into(ivPlace);


        }
```

I expect the data can be retrieved using ValueEventListener

Comment: If  you try to hardcode the name of the children, does it work?

Comment: What about your Firebase rules, can you show them?

Comment: @AlexMamo Thanks for your answer and I've just tried it, but it didn't work.

Comment: @Erik Here's my firebase rules
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}

Comment: @indira That are the actual values of `intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_LOCATION")` and `intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_POSITION")`?

Comment: @AlexMamo Yuppp, true.

Comment: Instead of using `intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_LOCATION")`, try to reproduce the problem with a hard-coded value for the path. If you can't reproduce it with a hard-coded value, you know the problem is in what is stored in `intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_LOCATION")`. If you can reproduce it with a hard-coded value, update the code in your question with the hard-coded values. See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Here are some things users often misses:

- Firebase rules are missing, the default is to block
- Forgot to download the google-services.json
- Spelling error in keys names vs code
- the marshal Java pojo has wrong method declaration or missing the set method

Another thing often overlooked is that if Offline Capabilities is on like:

> FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);

While debugging the app one can forget that data changed in the Firebase need to be propagated to the device before the device can react to the change. This is happening seemingly but if internet is flaky or other Intern hick ups strange things can happen that your not aware of right away

Like this [Firebase offline capabilities causing memory problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47212223/firebase-offline-capabilities-causing-memory-problems) answer by @AlexMamo and the discussion show..

If you experience strangness you can always uninstall app to release the local persisted version of the app db..

When developing one can by mistake view the wrong DB in Firestore console, lets say your app have a developer version and a production version, to little coffee and one might looking at wrong stuff